# How can I replace a value of dictionary based on a key condition in the same YAML file?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I have a YAML values file and I want to update the particular value of a dictionary based on its key via Ansible playbooks.

**`input.yaml`**

```yaml
operator:
  operator:
    replicaCount: 1
    env:
      - name: namespace1
        value: abc
      - name: namespace2
        value: xyz
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 200m
        memory: 256Mi
        ephemeral-storage: 500Mi
  console:
    replicaCount: 1
```

I want update the value of `namespace1` as `test` under `env` array in the `input.yaml`.

**Expected Result** in **`input.yaml`**

```yaml
operator:
  operator:
    replicaCount: 1
    env:
      - name: namespace1
        value: test
      - name: namespace2
        value: xyz
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 200m
        memory: 256Mi
        ephemeral-storage: 500Mi
  console:
    replicaCount: 1
```

Comment: Does [How to replace a value of dictionary based on a key condition in values.yaml via Ansible playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76724470/6771046) answer your question?

Comment: Hi @U880D, Thanks for your comment. But the solution for the above link doesn't fulfill completely. Actually, I posted both the questions. :) From that solution, am not able to replace the updated dictionary in input.yaml

Comment: Since it answer the question for me, what doesn't fulfill it for you? Are there any question regarding the solution? "_not able to replace the updated dictionary in `input.yaml`_", does this mean you want to edit or update a text file?

Comment: Yes, I want to update a particular namespace value in env array in the **input.yaml** file. I want the updated file completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According your description I wonder if you could use the [update_fact module – Update currently set facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/update_fact_module.html)? It is intended for updating variables and one of the documented [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/update_fact_module.html#examples) seems to be similar to yours.

Based on the former (or already) given answer and [Ansible: How to update or change a value in a nested dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76728823/6771046), a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - include_vars:
      file: input.yaml
      name: input

  - ansible.utils.update_fact:
      updates:
        - path: input.operator.operator.env[0]
          value: { name: namespace1, value: test}
    register: updated

  - debug:
      var: updated

  - copy:
      dest: output.yaml
      content: "{{ updated.input | to_nice_yaml(indent=2) }}"
```

will result into the requested `output.yaml` file

```yaml
operator:
  console:
    replicaCount: 1
  operator:
    env:
    - name: namespace1
      value: test
    - name: namespace2
      value: xyz
    replicaCount: 1
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 200m
        ephemeral-storage: 500Mi
        memory: 256Mi
```

Please take note that even if using [`update_fact` module – Update currently set facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/update_fact_module.html)

> *Variables are not modified in place, instead they are returned by the module.*

and [that is the expected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48825995/6771046).

**Further Q&A**

- [Variable as a YAML tree - How to save indent?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51084569/6771046)

Comment: One doubt - Instead of hard coding the 0th index (- path: input.operator.operator.env[0]), can we loop the env array in update_fact utils

Comment: "_can we loop the `env` array in `update_fact` utils_", on such I haven't worked yet, therefore, I don't know at the moment.

Comment: okay, I just tried with env (-path: valuesFile.operator.operator.env), it is replacing the entire env array. It means it removes all other values. Do you know any way to append as new entry in existing env array

Comment: Are you like to append an additional new key:value and not updating an existing one? But then you have two keys with the same name and different values.

Comment: Yes, tried and not possible. And looping with items won't support for update_fact... We can't give item from a loop to "path" attribute